# Working with Android RAM?

Tags: android, ram

My application based on time and attendance. There i required to save templates into database. To Matching the templates with database is take more time than LINUX OS. So, i planned to store those templates into RAM and have to done the matching process at RAM itself. I need a help how to move those templates into RAM. And also improve processing speed.

Hardware Spec:

```
  > ARM 335x , 256 RAM , 720 Mhz.
```

Answer (score 0):

you may download [NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) and code your template matching in C/C++ for speed